# Orchard v.1.10 Forum module

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

I am using Orchard v.1.10.0.0
I installed and enabled the forums module (Forums - Version: 1.0.1)

I dont see the forums in the admin menu. What am i missing?

I found in the db (i am using SQL server) in table [Orchard_Recipes_RecipeStepResultRecord]
Id ExecutionId RecipeName StepId StepName IsCompleted IsSuccessful ErrorMessage
7 23ba680e4956415e960aa2033ddc119c Test NGM.Forum Feature 1 0 Could not enable feature 0 because it was not found.

Any advice?

Comment: Check the logs. Probably the Forums module is outdated and you need to update the .Net target framework (the logs probably will say something like No loader found for module Forums, meaning it can't compile the project)

Comment: @devqon thanks. where do i change the .net framework?

Comment: Open the .csproj file and look for `<TargetFrameworkVersion>`, make it the same as the other .csproj files of your orchard version

Comment: @devqon you are the man!! thanks. ill post it in an answer. many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution.
The Orchard was compiled with reference to System.Web.Mvc version 5.2.3
and the forums module was compiled with a lower version.
I installed MVC 5 and re-refernced the System.Web.Mvc.
That solved the problem.